# remover partes de uma string e retornar as partes removidas - Swift

Tags: string, ios, swift, swift-3

Como eu faço para remover partes de uma string e retornar essas partes removidas para outra string em Swift?

Exemplo:

```
var myString = "10setembro2017"
let newString = myString.removeAndReturn(index:1..2)

print(myString) //setembro2017
print(newString) //10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso é bem mais complexo que parece, mas vou tentar explicar detalhadamente o passo a passo.

Primeiro você precisa trocar o tipo do parâmetro da sua função para `...` que no caso se chama `CountableClosedRange<Int>` mas `String` em Swift não usa `Int` como índice e sim `String.Index`.

Para converter Int em index você precisa usar um método da `String` chamado `index(String.Index, offsetBy: Int)`. Para converter o inicio da sua subrange voce precisa passar o `startIndex` da sua `String` e o `lowerBound` da sua range como offset.

Vale lembrar que os indices no Swift começam em zero e não em um.

Para converter o `upperBound` da sua range no `endIndex` da sua subrange você pode offset o `lowerBound` para não fazer duas vezes o offset do `lowerBound` desnecessariamente e passe a propriedade count da sua range (que é igual a diferença do `upperBound` menos o `lowerBound`).

Depois você salva a substring da sua `String` em um object que pode ser declarado como constante e usa o método removeSubrange para remover a subrange da sua `String` (voce precisa declarar o método como mutating para poder alterar a sua `String`).

Terminado isso é você só retornar uma nova String inicializada com a substring que você salvou antes de remover a subrange.

E pra completar `@discardableResult` deixa que você use esse método e decarte o resultado.

**Xcode 10.2 • Swift 5**

```
extension StringProtocol where Self: RangeReplaceableCollection {
    @discardableResult
    mutating func remove(range: ClosedRange<Int>) -> SubSequence {
        let lowerBound = index(startIndex, offsetBy: range.lowerBound)
        let upperBound = index(lowerBound, offsetBy: range.count)
        let subrange = lowerBound..<upperBound
        defer { removeSubrange(subrange) }
        return self[subrange]
    }
}
```

---

```
var string = "10setembro2017"
let range = 0...1
if string.count > range.upperBound {
    let dia = string.remove(range: range)
    print(dia) // "10\n"
    print(string)  // "setembro2017\n"
}
```

Comment: Se quiser estudar mais um pouco como subscript uma String usando Int recomendo voce olhar essa resposta que eu postei no site em ingles https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24092884/get-nth-character-of-a-string-in-swift-programming-language/38215613?s=1|43.0409#38215613 e olha também a resposta que um amigo meu Sueco chamado dfri  postou ontem. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46941709/2303865

Comment: Muito boa resposta. O que você acha de acrescentar uma nota falando que o método irá gerar um  *crash* se for utilizado um *range* negativo e/ou maior que o tamanho da string?